# Rails routes, kind of synonym routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

**Statement**

Imagine we have an inventory app, there it is a `Movement` model, it represent any movement like products purchase or products sale. So we have default REST routes.

```
    movements GET    /movements(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"movements"}
              POST   /movements(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"movements"}
 new_movement GET    /movements/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"movements"}
edit_movement GET    /movements/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movements"}
     movement GET    /movements/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movements"}
              PUT    /movements/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"movements"}
              DELETE /movements/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"movements"}
```

For **mnemonic proposes**, we want to have some descriptive routes, like:

```
 new_purchase        /purchase/new(.:format)       {:controller=>"movements", :action=>"new_purchase"}
edit_purchase        /purchase/:id/edit(.:format)  {:controller=>"movements", :action=>"edit_purchase"}
```

If you can see `purchase`'s are same model like`movement`'s, actually are processed by `MovementsController`, but there with have different flow and treatment, this specified by `create_purchase` instead of `create`.

**Questions**

1. How should I add restful routes for `purchase`'s? Taking care of specify HTTP methods like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc.
2. How should I write `form_for` tags? Using `movement` model we can write: `<%= form_for(@movement) do |f| %>` but how is to call `purchase` paths for `create` or `update` methods?
3. How should I specify validation rules for `purchase`'s? I have specified some rules on `Movement` model, but they are not applied for `purchase`'s when a form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some thing like this in your routes file

```
 match '/purchase/new(.:format)' => 'movements#new_purchase'     :via => :get
 match '/purchase/:id/edit(.:format)' => 'movements#edit_purchase' :via => :post
```

and you can mention others like delete, put in :via

for more info look at this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
 If you want to change create to create_purchases go to the movements controller and change the definition names.

for the second question you could do something like this

```
form_tag(:controller => "controller_name", :action => "action_name", :method => "get")
```

Comment: I have added a second question to the post.

Comment: Using `:via` options was useful to specify HTTP methods.

Comment: Hope the updated answer solves the your second question. Try googling your question first. If you cant find an answer in google you can post then here :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you should be looking for a way to RESTfully build routes for a model that handles an object in two separate ways. That sounds to me like you're really looking for two objects. You can create a `Purchase` model that inherits its properties from a parent `Movement` model.

Alternatively, you could assume that they are the same object and handle them the same way with semantic paths that make sense. That said, what you're looking for may be a path alteration for the default RESTful routes of the `Movement` controller actions. Also, a typical rails convention is to use plural path routes, which makes semantic sense for index pages and identifying objects that are a subset of a table of objects in a database, so I'm using `purchases` instead of `purchase`.

```
resources :movements, :path => "/purchases"
```

will produce

```
    movements GET    /purchases(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"movements"}
              POST   /purchases(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"movements"}
 new_movement GET    /purchases/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"movements"}
edit_movement GET    /purchases/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movements"}
     movement GET    /purchases/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movements"}
              PUT    /purchases/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"movements"}
              DELETE /purchases/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"movements"}
```

Using this model, the `form_for` helper method can still be used just like you would normally. Assuming `@movement` is properly defined, the path with the `purchases` root will be called properly.